# why maxrecursion didn't work if I specify singularity in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I study sigularity specification and MaxRecursion in NIntegrate. And find something unusual.

first I define a function

```
δ[x_, y_: 1/100] := 1/π*y/(x^2 + y^2)
```

Plot δ[x - 2]

```
Plot[δ[x - 2], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

gives
  [image]

Now NIntegrate δ[x - 2] from -∞ to +∞，I control the MaxRecursion option, and plot the sample points using the `plotrecur` function. I will give `plotrecur` in the end.

```
Table[{"MaxRecursion" i, 
plotrecur[δ[x - 2], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
MaxRecursion -> i]}, {i, 4, 9}]
```

this gives

[image]

the above picture shows that how reducing `MaxRecursion` step by step will affect sample points used in NIntegrate.

then I exclude 2 as a singularity in the integration interval. through 2 is actually not a singularity, but it is sharp.

```
Table[{"MaxRecursion" i, 
plotrecur[\[Delta][x - 2], {x, -\[Infinity], 2,\[Infinity]}, 
MaxRecursion -> i]}, {i, 4, 9}]
```

[image]

we can see that the `MaxRecursion` doesn't affect the sampling until `MaxRecursion` reduced to 4.

**It's hard for me to understand this. I think the only effect after specifying a singularity manually is to let *Mathematica* trigger a singularityhandler(e.g. IMT or DoubleExponential) at that point. Is this view right? Why will specifying singularity makes `MaxRecursion` invalid? Can somebody give a explanation**

---

Finally, the `plotrecur` function here:

```
plotrecur[integrand_, {x_, low_, singularity___, high_}, 
opt___] := {Length@#[[2, 1]], #[[1]], 
ListPlot[
 Transpose[{Transpose[#[[2, 1]]][[1]], 
   Range[Length@#[[2, 1]]]}]]} &[
Reap[NIntegrate[integrand, {x, low, singularity, high}, opt, 
EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, integrand}]]]]
```

Comment: I confirm this behavior for v. 8.0.4. Similar behavior occurs if one specify exclusions using the `Exclusions` option.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What you are seeing is that 5 recursions (within each of the sub-intervals {-Infinity, 2} and {2, Infinity}) are sufficient to solve the integral to within PrecisionGoal -> Automatic.

Comment: @AndrewMoylan Hi,I am sorry. I cannot understand what you mean. 5 recursions is not sufficient.

Comment: Isn't the exact value of the integral 1? With MaxRecursion -> 5, and splitting the integration region first at x == 2, NIntegrate converges to 1. Thus 5 recursions are sufficient. And any MaxRecursion -> n for n > 5 should be expected to be identical.